# BASH Recursive Function

Tags: bash

I have a test site that performs a chain of 302 redirects.  I'm looking to write a BASH script that will print the redirect URL from the response header from each page in the chain.

The following command will strip the URL from an individual response header and print it.

```sh
$ curl -Is http://iperformalotofredirects.com/ | sed -ne 's/Location: //' -e6p
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/

$ curl -Is http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/ | sed -ne 's/Location: //' -e6p
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/nextstep/
```

I wrote a python script that functions properly, but for the sake of research, I'm also trying to do the same thing in a BASH script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

geturl() {
  if [[ $1 == http* ]]
  then
    echo $1
    geturl $(curl -Is $1 | sed -ne 's/Location: //' -e6p)
  fi
}

geturl http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
```

The script comes up empty after the first iteration

```sh
$ ./curlit.sh
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/
```

What I need is for the script to continue until exhaustion.  My manual results show that more comes after `http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/` whereas my script is failing at achieving this.

**Edit:**
Included @konsolebox's answer as reference

```sh
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    local location=$1

    while [[ $location == http* ]]; do
        echo "$location"
        location=$(curl -Is "$location" | awk '/Location: / { print $2 }')
    done
}

main "$@"
```

Copied and pasted this script identically.  Ran it:

```
$ ./curlit.sh http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/
```

What I expect to see:

```
$ ./curlit.sh http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/nextstep/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/anotherstep/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/moresteps/
http://iperformalotofredirects.com/finalstep/
```

**Edit:** fravadona requested the entire header

```
$ curl -Is http://iperformalotofredirects.com/
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 09:20:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 145
Location: http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -Is http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 09:20:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 145
Location: http://iperformalotofredirects.com/nextstep/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: So what do you need? If you're asking for a review, consider posting in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Also, Bash does not support tail call optimization so soon enough you would reach "stack overflow" with that code.

Comment: @konsolebox I'm not asking for a review. I thought it was apparent. I added a sentence at the bottom of the original post for explanation.

Comment: I appreciate the info about the stack overflow.  Definitely not looking to break anything.  I'd be happy to have the recursive function changed out for a while loop.  I tried something similar, and failed at that attempt.

Comment: How about against `https://kernel.org`, did it work as you expected or not?

Comment: What is the entire response header when inquiring `http://iperformalotofredirects.com/firststep/`?

Comment: `https://kernel.org/` does not have a chain of redirects.  I tested this manually to be certain.  `curl -Is https://kernel.org/` will show `https://kernel.org/` on the `Location` line.  However, I did run your script against it, and it stops after 2 lines, just as it does against my custom site.

Comment: Every recursion needs an end condition.

Comment: `curl -Is https://kernel.org/` will show `https://www.kernel.org/`.

Comment: @ceving the end condition is shown in my `if` statement.

Comment: @konsolebox please see my entire header added to the OP.  It shows a new address.

Comment: Yes, I have a complete list of the redirects. I can successfully achieve this script in python.  There were 8 total redirects I think.  `curl` will successfully retrieve the header from each redirect until the end, if I perform it manually.  I'm really just trying to complete this bash script for research and training purposes.

Comment: Try adding a delay between loops. Like `sleep 5`.

Comment: Added `sleep 5` as requested.  No change, aside from the time difference.

Comment: @konsolebox I clicked the `continue in chat` link at the bottom of the page, if you would like to go there.

Comment: Sure but so far I'm out of ideas. My script should work against the second header output you just placed. I ran awk against it manually and it printed the URL. Try to debug the responses you receive. See the modification I made to my answer.

Comment: I agree with debugging the responses.  I have done this manually.  Each response turns out the same.  I feel confident in the `awk` and the `sed` statement for stripping the required information to pass as an argument for the next iteration.  I have verified each step manually just to be certain.  I also added debugging info, and it appears that the function receives the URL and only the URL as argument.  I believe there is a nesting issue when it comes to the command.  One moment please, while I review your update.

Comment: @konsolebox please see the screenshot uploaded to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for debugging:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    local location=$1

    while [[ $location == http* ]]; do 
        printf '%q\n' "$location"
        location=$(curl -Is "$location" | awk '/^Location: / { print $2 }')
    done
}

main "$@"
```

For me, running `main https://kernel.org` outputs
`$'https://www.kernel.org/\r'`, which means that there might be an unwanted carriage return at the end of the location.

A possible fix would be to strip that carriage return:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    local location=$1

    while [[ $location == http* ]]; do 
        printf '%q\n' "$location"
        location=$(curl -Is "$location" | awk '/^Location: / { print $2 }')
        location=${location%$'\r'}
    done
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: This definitely it. I thought about CRLF but only about the script.

Comment: Good call.  Let me have a look.